# How to format kendo pivot grid column header

Tags: kendo-grid

I have been trying to format the date of the kendo pivot grid column header.

I have a date property in the data which I used as column in the kendo pivot grid dataSource columns

```
var dS = new kendo.data.PivotDataSource({
  .... All regular stuff to read the data.
 columns:[{"name":"Date", "expand":"true", "template":"#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(Date),'MMMM, yyyy') #"}]
});
```

The date data comes like "2015-06-05T00:00:00Z"

When the pivot grid is drawn, I want to format the pivot grid column header. I have mentioned the type as Date in the schema model. Here is the link to my try. http://dojo.telerik.com/iTInI

The column header is not formatted. I wanted it to display as Month, year like May, 2015 but instead it is displaying is Sun May 31 2015 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

Please help me to format the column header.

Thanks for the time and help